# Is my scala Regex pattern is the correct way to represent?

Tags: regex, scala

```
val pass = "123 Enter right number from (10,5,3,3,200,6)"
 val pattern = """\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+""".r
val pp = pattern.findfirstIn(pass)
println(pp)
```

Yes I got it extracted as

```
10,5,3,3,200,6
```

which is what i needed

My question is, is this

```
val pattern = """\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+""".r
```

the correct way to represent regex pattern....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, certainly. However, you can do some really cool stuff with it involving Scala's pattern matching if you enhance your pattern with capturing groups:

```
val pattern = """.*?(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+).*?""".r
val pattern(d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5) = pass
```